# intrusive_ptr using a base class for ref count and include cycles hell

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

I'm using `boost::intrusive_ptr` as my reference counted smart pointer. I'm using something like this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/stl/boostsmartptr.aspx#intrusive_ptr%20-%20lightweight%20shared%20pointer

This seems a good idea, because it simplifies the declaration of a new Reference counted class, just inheriting from it. The problem comes with forward declarations. There are a lot of places where I want to use a pointer to a type not yet decladed in a class definiton and it is not possible, because the 2 methods that handle ref count need to know if the type inherits from CRefCounted or not.

If I try to include the dependencies before the declaration of the intrusive_ptr it is ok, but then, I get a lot of cyclic includes.

How would you handle this scenario?

Comment: Slightly offtopic, but there is a serious flaw with the CRefCounted class in the link because it doesn't define a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using a similar RefCounted base class a lot and I started wondering why do I never have this problem. And it's because I tend to hide implementation details in source files. Consider the following header file of class B:

```
//File: B.h
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>

class A;

class B
{
public:
    B();
    ~B();
    boost::intrusive_ptr<A> foo();
    void foo2(const boost::intrusive_ptr<A> p);
    boost::intrusive_ptr<A> p;
};
```

It works, because even though it is using intrusive_ptr, it doesn't need to instantiate its constructor or destructor. Therefore it doesn't need to know anything about the class A.

The place where it needs to know about A is in the source file. (And also in places where foo/foo2 are called). B's constructor and destructor implicitly call intrusive_ptr< A>'s constructor/destructor, so A's definition must be available.

```
//File: B.cpp
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h" //Include header where A is defined.

B::B() { }
B::~B() { }

//Other member functions...
```

I don't know if this helps in your case, but it's something to think about. :)

Comment: Well, I finally managed to solve it.Your answer put me on the right path. I usually do same thing you exposed. The problem is this dumb apple compiler that was giving bad or mislead information about the error. I extracted all files from the project and was adding them one by one and the problem was the type was not completed, just a forward declaration.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can solve this using templates functions for `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` and `intrusive_ptr_release` as follows:

```
namespace boost {
  template<class T> void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(T* p) { ++(p->references) }
  template<class T>void intrusive_ptr_release(T* p) { 
    if (--(p->references) == 0) 
      delete p 
  }
};
```

You'll also need to adapt the friend declarations in `CRefCounted` like

```
template class<T> friend void ::boost::intrusive_ptr_add_ref(T*);
template class<T> friend void ::boost::intrusive_ptr_release(T*);
```

Using these declarations, you can use `intrusive_ptr` on forward-declared classes like

```
class A;
class B {
  ::boost::intrusive_ptr<A> _myPtr;
};
class A : public CRefCounted {
};
```

This solution has the drawback (theoretically...), that you define a pair of `add_ref`/`release` functions for *every* subclass of `CRefCounted`, but I think that the compiler will choose to use inlining anyway, so this can be neglected.

Comment: I tried this solution before posting but did not solve the problem, obviously because compiler was cheating. Thanks for the effort.